# Pre-processing a line for csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file with csv.reader. However, one of the fields in this file is not properly encoded. It is a string enclosed in double quotes, but the double quotes within the string are not escaped.

```
id,name,score
1,"something" like this",20
```

As there is only one field like this, I should be able to correct this field by looking for the first and last double quotes and escape any double quotes between them. Is there any way to preprocess a line before csv.reader processes it to achieve something like this?

Comment: Can you just iterate over the file and split each on commas - not using `csv`?

Comment: Surely to pre-process it using Python you would have to read it first - and that would need csv.reader? An alternative would to be to do something using the bash shell. There are some hints [here] (https://pixorblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/csv-files-and-bash/ )

Comment: Why do you need to use a `csv reader`?

Comment: Yes, you can pre-process lines for `csv.reader`. I'll post an example in a minute or two.

Comment: Is there some other quoting in the file? You could create a csv reader with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Comment: @wwii the quoted string can have commas. I really don't need to use csv reader but I would like to use anything that can handle csv format (rfc4180) in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) will happily read lines from any iterable, including a generator, so we can use a generator to do the quote escaping. But we also need to tell `csv.reader` about our [escapechar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar).

I've embedded some test data as a list of strings into this code, but you can  pass an open file to the `fixlines` generator.

```
import csv 

data = '''\
id,name,score
1,"something" like this",20
2,"another thing" like that",30
'''.splitlines()

def fixlines(lines):
    for row in lines:
        try:
            first = row.index('"') + 1
            last = row.rindex('"')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            stuff = row[first:last].replace('"', '\\"')
            row = row[:first] + stuff + row[last:]
        yield row

reader = csv.reader(fixlines(data), escapechar='\\')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
['id', 'name', 'score']
['1', 'something" like this', '20']
['2', 'another thing" like that', '30']
```

This code makes no changes to lines that contain no double-quotes (like the header line), or a pair of double-quotes, but it may not do exactly what you want if it finds a line containing a single double-quote. Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

However, it does handle commas inside the quoted string correctly.

---

This also works with [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
reader = csv.DictReader(fixlines(data), escapechar='\\')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'something" like this'), ('score', '20')])
OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('name', 'another thing" like that'), ('score', '30')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below, where `test.csv` is your CSV file:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\'')
    for row in readCSV:
        row[1] = str(row[1])[1:-1]
        print("{0} | {1} | {2}".format(row[0], row[1].replace('"', '\\"'), row[2]))
```

This gives:

```
id | am | score
1 | something\" like this | 20
2 | hello\" world | 50
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but you can chain generators and use a regex to process lines as they are read into the csv reader instead of preprocessing the entire file into a list.

```
import re
import csv
import io

csv_file = io.StringIO("""\
id,name,score
1,"something" like this",20
111,"something", comma'd, like this",202020""")

def requote_line(line):
    try:
        before, mid, after = re.match('(.*?")(.*)(".*)', line).groups()
        return before + mid.replace('"', '') + after
        # or `mid.replace('"', '""')` if you want to keep the quotes
    except AttributeError:
        return line

reader = csv.reader(requote_line(line) for line in csv_file)
table = list(reader)
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

Running, prints

```
['id', 'name', 'score']
['1', 'something like this', '20']
['111', "something, comma'd, like this", '202020']
```